# wild card subdomain apache+tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts

I have my struts project hosted on apache and tomcat server.I need a wildcard subdomain on my server.
I write the following code on Apaches virtualhost .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs/projects/myprj"
    ServerAlias *.asd.mydomain.com
    ServerName asd.mydomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.jsp
```

I cahnged my tomcat server.xml docbase to /var/www/htdocs/projects

But my subdomains are not working.when i take 123.asd.mydomain.com , it loads tomcats home page.

Anybody knows what is the issue,If i did anything more?want to write anything on .htaccess

Thanks,
Shihab.

Comment: I can't see how these two directives alone are passing your requests to Tomcat. Are you using mod_jk or ProxyPass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides matching  vrtual host, you nees some rules to pass your request to tomcat - 
either rewrite rules,  or proxy pass like :

```
RewriteRule ^/xxx/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/yp/$1 [L,P]

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```